# Drools 6.5 Error Compiling Rule Referencing A Map

Tags: drools

I'm trying to compile the following rule and getting an error `The method concatenateValues(String, String, String) in the type StringHelper is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object)`. My question is why does $map.get("KEY_B"),.. not return a String value?

```
rule "RULE01"   
    no-loop true
    when
        $attribute:String()
        $map : Map(this["KEY_A"] == "VALUE_A")
    then
        ruleResponse.put("ruleName",drools.getRule().getName());
        $attribute = StringHelper.concatenateValues($map.get("KEY_B"),$map.get("KEY_C"), $map.get("KEY_D"));
        ruleResponse.put("result",$attribute);
end


public static String concatenateValues(Object value1, Object value2, Object value3){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value1 == null ? "" : value1.toString())
                                     .append(value2 == null ? "" : value2.toString())
                                     .append(value3 == null ? "" : value3.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools is not aware of generic types. The results of get have type `Object`.

You could fix your `StringHelper.concatenateValues` to operate like this:

```
StringHelper.concatenateValues( Object o1, Object o2, Object o3 ){
    return concatenateValues( o1.toString, o2.toString, o3.toString );
}
```

Comment: Thank you laune, I've posted my update to `StringHelper.concatenateValues` above